# How can the Maven unique version string be customized?

Tags: maven-2, continuous-integration

I'd like to know what options exist to customize the timestamp string used in Maven artifact deploys when 
`<uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>` is set.  Ideally, we'd like to include the changelist number from source control instead of a timestamp as it's a more dependable means of determining what features and bug fixes are in a given build.

Comment: Why not making a relationship between the version and your version control system to mark particular milestones which represent particular list of fixed issues in your issue tracking system. (If you use maven 3 the above configuration does not work anymore).

Comment: Not certain what you mean by "making a relationship" between the version number and the changelist number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'd like to know what options exist to customize the timestamp string used in Maven artifact deploys when true is set.

You can't customize it, the timestamped string is a well defined internal thing that is supposed to be used as is, or not (if you set `uniqueVersion` to `false` in the `distributionManagement` element).

From the Maven book (for readers interested, it won't really help you):

> #### [3.3.1.2. SNAPSHOT Versions](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html#pom-relationships-sect-snapshot-versions)
>
> Maven versions can contain a string
>   literal to signify that a project is
>   currently under active development. If
>   a version contains the string
>   “SNAPSHOT,” then Maven will expand
>   this token to a date and time value
>   converted to UTC (Coordinated
>   Universal Time) when you install or
>   release this component. For example,
>   if your project has a version of
>   “1.0-SNAPSHOT” and you deploy this
>   project’s artifacts to a Maven
>   repository, Maven would expand this
>   version to “1.0-20080207-230803-1” if
>   you were to deploy a release at 11:08
>   PM on February 7th, 2008 UTC. In other
>   words, when you deploy a snapshot, you
>   are not making a release of a software
>   component; you are releasing a
>   snapshot of a component at a specific
>   time.

Comment: That's as thorough an answer as I could hope for.  Thanks.

Comment: I have tried all ways to tell Maven not to add the timestamps (m-d-p `<configuration>`, `<dependencyManagement>, and `-DuniqueVersion`, and still it's being uploaded with a snapshot. Is this expected? Or forced by the repo somehow?