# force mvn to set timestamp instead of SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven-2

Can I force maven to build and install an artifact with a specific timestamp instead of SNAPSHOT ? How?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is the uniqueversion setting on the [deploy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html). There is also another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935932/how-can-the-maven-unique-version-string-be-customized) that addresses this same issue.